# Yum update producing error on a package - so no packages update

Tags: linux, repository, redhat, yum

I've run a yum update and am getting the below errors:

```
Downloading packages:
scx-1.6.4-7.universal.x64.rpm  FAILED
https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/prod/scx-1.6.4-7.universal.x64.rpm: [Errno -1] Package does not match intended download. Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=packages-microsoft-com-prod clean metadata
Trying other mirror.


Error downloading packages:
  scx-1.6.4-7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Running the suggested command did not work

Due to this it seems none of the other packages update - Is there a way to exclude this and update the others or resolve the errors?

Comment: As your text says : "Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=packages-microsoft-com-prod clean metadata " .... The package *is* present https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/prod/

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that running that command seemed to not do anything - still got the exact same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yum update --exclude=scx excluded the package. But that surly doesn't solve the probem with that package itself.

Comment: Marked as answered as the premise of the question was how to exclude a package